# linux failed to assign local port

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, tcp-ip

Our nginx reported a error below:

```
2017/10/19 10:47:40 [crit] 41689#0: *23414459 connect() to 127.0.0.1:1234 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:1234/", host: "www.example.com"
```

which means nginx failed to request a local port when try to connect to upstream. But I find that this problem emerges when local ports for all ips used up. check below:

```
Thu Oct 19 10:47:40 CST 2017
54997 <- system wide local ports used. 54997 is the max for my server, here nginx begin reporting errors
22.140.119.4 44543 <- local ports used for public ip
127.0.0.1 19978    <- local ports used for 127.0.0.1
```

So my question is why assign failed since only 19978 local ports used for loopback ip ?

system info

```
nginx: openresty/1.11.2.1
kernel: Linux 4.9
distro: Ubuntu 14.04
```